# How to run GUI application on Docker in root mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ettercap

I need to use ettercap-graphical in docker, but it only works in root mode and the GUI does not work in GUI.

Comment: Please ask this question on Docker forum, this is a developer's den. https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-run-a-gui-application-on-docker/48437

Comment: If you need to run an application with access to the host network interfaces and the host display, you actively do not want the isolation layer that Docker provides.  Run the program directly on the host.